# Função tem tela em tempo real, trava a tela com o tempo!

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Eu estou estudando ajax, jquery e php. E com o objetivo de fazer uma tela que carrega automaticamente, para futuramente fazer chat. O que eu quero entender é a função de carregamento de tela.

Eu tenho o código index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?php 
require "bd.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Ajax With Jquery</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      function autoRefresh_div()
 {
      $("#result").load("index.php").show();// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
  }

  setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 4000);
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="result">
     <?php 
       if($sql->rowCount() > 0){

           foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $dados){
               echo "mensagem: ".$dados['mensagem']."<br>";
           }
       }
     ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu tenho o código bd.php

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=realtime;host=localhost";
$dbname = "root";
$dbpass = "";
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbname, $dbpass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat";
$sql = $pdo->query($sql);
?>
```

O problema que conforme o tempo, a tela trava pelo fato de enviar várias requisições e isso está deixando o servidor pesado e trava a tela de navegação. Tem alguma coisa que posso melhorar o código para evitar esse problema?

Comment: Aconselhava usares AJAX com retorno em json o que é boa pratica para aplicações deste tipo

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo, por favor

Comment: já faço uma resposta um momento

Comment: Olá @Alan, em minha resposta citei alguns tópicos quais você deverá estudar para melhorar todo esse processo e também coloquei a resolução do problema mais grave - qual está causando esse overload no seu servidor.

Comment: Ok, irei estudar melhor nos conceitos que me passou. Estou estudando mais funções para poder utilizar a minha lógica para outras coisas. Muito obrigado!

Comment: `Websocket`... O problema é que vc vai consumir recurso de rede fazendo várias requisições pro banco usando o navegador. Eu acredito que a melhor saída é usar `websocket`. Se ninguém conseguir responder, eu tento...

Comment: @ShutUpMagda poderia criar uma resposta mostrando como faria com websocket pois ninguem mostrou nada ainda com websocket, acho que seria interessante.

Comment: @ViniciusPuttiMorais essa resposta é canônica... Tem que trabalhar ela direitinho. Demora... Por isso que eu falei que se ninguém tentar responder de uma forma simples, eu tento responder depois ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que fazes uma conexão e com intervalos pequenos e deixando a mesma aberta .

O mais correto nesta situação seria usar **ajax** com retorno de **json** o que consome menos do servidor
Então vou dar um pequeno exemplo:

### Na parte do servidor (PHP)

Cria um ficheiro a parte como `connection.php` com a conexão a DB:

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=realtime;host=localhost";
$dbname = "root";
$dbpass = "";
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbname, $dbpass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

depois no ficheiro index.php inclui o ficheiro connection.php no mesmo, assim:

```
<?php

include('connection.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat";
$sql = $pdo->query($sql);
```

Não te esqueças de fechar a conexão, exemplo:

```
$pdo = null;
```

No final de teres tudo pronto retorna todos os dados em json usando a função `json_encode()`

```
return json_encode(['dado1' => 'valor1', 'dado2' => 'valor2']);
```

### Na parte do cliente (javascript/jquery)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
     $.ajax({url: "index.php", success: function(data){
                    // receber o json
                    var data = JSON.parse(data);
                    // daqui podes usar o json assim
                    $("#dado1").append(data.dado1);
            }});
     }, 4000);
});
```

Então o `setTimeout` ira fazer a requisição ajax ao **index.php** com intervalo de 4 segundos e ira receber dado formatado em json onde podes começar a construir o html com o mesmo!

Comment: `setInterval` vai sobrecarregar...  [referência](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: @ShutUpMagda Editado, obrigado pelo aviso!

Answer (score 3):

Um dos problemas mais grave que está causando o travamento, é que você, a cada 4000 milissegundos (4 segundos) está abrindo uma nova conexão com o banco de dados! É por isso que ele com o tempo vai ficando sobrecarregado.

Faça o seguinte, num arquivo separado db.php

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=realtime;host=localhost";
$dbname = "root";
$dbpass = "";
try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbname, $dbpass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Chame esse arquivo apenas uma vez, para conectá-lo ao banco de dados, e mantenha o seu index.php (o arquivo que será usado na sua requisição Ajax):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat";
$sql = $pdo->query($sql);
```

### **Atenção!!!**

Existe inúmeros problemas com o seu código, desde críticos à não-críticos. O qual eu abordei, é o que diminuirá bastante a sobrecarga do teu server. Porém, para fins didáticos (já que vc está estudando), vou lhe passar todos os probleminhas e com isso seria legal vc os estudar:

1. Está utilizando código PHP no HTML (isso não é uma boa prática)
2. Invés de utilizar esse código PHP no HTML (`$sql->rowCount(), etc`), no próprio arquivo index.php faça o resultado do *select* virar JSON utilizando a função `json_encode()` do PHP.
3. Invés de utilizar a função do jQuery `load()`, utilize a `$.ajax, $.get, $.getJSON` ... [Para estudar mais sobre esse terceiro item, acesse esse link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Claro que irá travar. O `setInterval` não é apropriado para isso.

O `setInterval`, no seu caso, irá executar a função após 4 segundos **independentemente** se o Ajax foi processado ou não. Isso é péssimo porque, caso o retorno do Ajax demore mais que o tempo setado, ele irá enviar outra requisição, e outra e outra e outra... causando um caos tanto no servidor quando no navegador.

O correto é você fazer um `setTimeout("autoRefresh_div()",4000);` **após** o retorno do Ajax.

Diferença básica entre `setInterval` e `setTimeout`:

- `SetInterval`: executa **ininterruptamente** a função após o tempo setado.
- `SetTimeout`: executa **apenas 1 vez** a função após o tempo setado.

Comment: Eu pensei nisso aí quando comentei lá na pergunta. Mas ainda acredito que a saída pra ele é `websocket`.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda Tb acho. Eu não tenho conhecimento do websocket, mas li alguma coisa a respeito e parece ser bem melhor para o propósito.

Answer (score 1):

Se voce esta usando ajax, entao voce deve ter uma funcao de callback, tente ao inves de usar setInterval fazer uma nova requisicao na funcao de callback das requisicoes:

```
// Nao sei como faz ajax no jquery mas deve ser mais ou menos assim
ajax(url, function () {
    //essa funcao vai executar quando terminar essa requisicao ajax
    nova_requisicao();
}, data);
```

É apenas um exemplo porque eu nao sei a sintaxe do jquery.